# Correct way to disable windows kernel mode driver activity

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver, wdm

I have several drivers for windows such as minifilter and driver for work with network. All drivers communiate with a special application and i need disable that drivers activity when a special application is not working (for example, this application may be killed using task manager). How i can do this properly?

For communication between special program and drivers i use IRP, but can't think how disable activity in this case because when program killed by task manager i can't send IRP to shutdown drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app has handle to your Driver (IRP_MJ_CREATE) you should get IRP_MJ_CLOSE
when the application closes the handle or crash (this is done by the OS)

Comment: I get both IRP_MJ_CLEANUP AND  IRP_MJ_CLOSE